# How do I make circle disappear if not clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making this game in JavaScript.

https:// jsfiddle .net/hffuhb1n/

(I separated the link because it won't let me submit for some reason)

Clicking a square gives you a certain number of points depending on how fast it was clicked. When a circle appears though, I want it to take away 800 points if clicked, and if not clicked in 2 seconds I want it to disappear again, and then another square or circle would appear and so forth.

I've looked all over and I can't figure out how to set the circle to disappear after 2 seconds so that another shape can appear afterwards.

Please help ~ Thanks!

Comment: This is why you can't add your fiddle link:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: You can use `setTimeout(function(){/*Do Things*/}, /*Time (ms)*/);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding this to your `function makeBox2(){` which is inside the function `level2Cir()` at the bottom gets your desired functinality

```
circleKiller = setTimeout(function(){
      boxDiv.style.display="none";
      level2(); 
    },2000); // 2 seconds
```

And then if at all the circle is clicked then we don't need to execute the circleKiller. So lets clear it off, Place this code right in beginning of the circle on click code.

```
 // v ON CLICK v
  boxDiv.onclick = function() {
      clearTimeout(circleKiller);
      .....
      .....
  }
```

Here is the **[working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hffuhb1n/7/)**

Comment: There is a floor in your logic. `boxDiv` is a global variable, so if the circle is clicked, the box currently on screen in 2 seconds will be hidden. This is not the circle that was clicked. You need to create a variable inside the function to store just that circle, like so: `var currentDiv = boxDiv`, then set `currentDiv.style.display` to `'none'`

Comment: @Druzion Thanks for the comment, But that not how it works, He wants to hide the circle after 2 secs if not clicked, So setting it as display none, At this point the `boxDiv` will be circle itself. If you see his logic he renders a new shape only after click, What I am doing is I am rendering after hiding.. Its the same..

Comment: @Druzion the OP just stays with the shape unless its clicked, Once it is clicked he is hiding it and then getting a new shape. Now in the circle shape the logic is similar but without a click, after 2 secs I am hiding it and getting a new shape. If the circle is clicked before 2 secs then the default hide and getting new shape executes, Here creating a new variable might not help. As the OP just has one div and he is changing the shapes of this ony div. Open inspect element and you can see it.

Comment: Yes, but assuming the circle was clicked, your code will still run after 2 seconds, correct? And if it runs after click, a new shape will have been created, and that new shape will be the one that is hidden. If you try playing the game in youe fiddle and click on the circles, you should see (after a few goes) that a shape after the circle disappears, just after it is shown.

Comment: Yes mate, you are right there, Just while giving you reply I realized that, I just need to clear interval in this case.. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, I thought I was wrong for a minute! ;)

Comment: Kind of you are :) because the variable will not help, we will end up in the same issue as you pointed out above.. :p

Comment: @Druzion updated my answer, Thanks for pulling me back into this :)

Comment: No, since the `currentDiv` variable will not be global, since it is defined inside the function. Therefore the `currentDiv` will always be the circle that has not been clicked. When the new shaped is generated (if the circle is clicked), `currentDiv` will be re-defined when the function is called again, but the original `currentDiv` corresponding to the original circle will not be overwritten. Basically, the variable must be defined inside the function, i.e. not be global.

Comment: So the variable would work, but `clearInterval()` is probably more efficient.

Comment: `boxDiv = document.getElementById("box");` this is the box div, Its the same div that is converted into diff shapes, So even if I save this into a new local variable it will still point to the same div right ?? So I am dealing with the same div right?? So the local variable `currentDiv` at any given point will point to that div itself  no matter what shape it is in.. Right?  :)

Comment: Yes, now I see it. I thought new `div`s were created for each shape, I did not read the code thoroughly enough. Thanks!

Comment: Initially I felts the same way and I also thought he is hiding all the divs instead of removing, But then I could find out the real thing..

Comment: @Reddy Thanks! It works perfectly! :D

Comment: @NickDuto if either mine or Druzion answer helped you to resolve the issue please mark the respected one as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout). It runs the function (first arg) after a duration specified in milliseconds (second arg), like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // Code...
}, time)
```

This will run the function after `time` milliseconds. So for 2 seconds you would use `2000`.

Also note that you can use `score += 100` to increase the score by 100, rather than `score = score + 100`

What you need to do is set a variable with the value of `800`

Inside the setInterval(), you could have an `if` statement checking if the circle has been clicked, and if it has not, subtract `800` points from the variable. Then `-` the variable from the score.

If the circle was not clicked, at the end of the 2 seconds the variable will be set to `0`. If it was, the variable will be `800`, and the score will have `800` subtracted

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hffuhb1n/9/)

I used the following code:

```
// v ON CLICK v
var clicked = false // Variable to store if it has been clicked
var thisboxdiv = boxDiv // To store current box div (to stop others being hidden)
boxDiv.onclick = function() {

    clicked = true // Set it to clicked
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    totalTime = totalTime + reactionTime;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalTime;

    score = score - 800;

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    this.style.display = "none";
    level2();

  }
  // ^ ON CLICK ^

var level2_in_2000 = setInterval(function() {
  // If div has not been clicked, switch to next level and hide div
  if (!clicked) {
    thisboxdiv.style.display = "none";
    level2()
  }
}, 2000)
```

---

**Update: Thanks to [@Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592042/reddy), I now realize it is more efficient to use `clearInterval()`, check out the new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hffuhb1n/9/), and the code below:**

```
var level2_in_2000 = setInterval(function() {
    // Hide div
    thisboxdiv.style.display = "none";
    level2()
}, 2000)

// v ON CLICK v
boxDiv.onclick = function() {

    clearInterval(level2_in_2000)
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    totalTime = totalTime + reactionTime;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totalTime;

    score = score - 800;

    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    this.style.display = "none";
    level2();

  }
  // ^ ON CLICK ^
```

Comment: I've up-voted yours. The downvote was definitely not fair and whoever did it is a pest.

Comment: may be because initially you had very little in your answer and it could have been put as a comment. I didn't down vote but I too felt that way, But now your answer seems valid

Comment: @KirillChatrov Thank you! ;)

Comment: I played in you fiddle and it starts going crazy, Like the speed of the shape toggle is too fast, It keeps increasing and goes super speed, Was this the intended behaviour??

Comment: @Reddy I know, I am updating my code (it crashed the browser!)

Comment: @Reddy, Fixed it, and I have used clearInterval()

Comment: @NickDuto No Problem! If this answered your question, would you mind marking it as accepted (press the tick underneath the voting buttons)?